# iPhone App - WAV sound files don't play

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, audio

I searched on here and tried out all the different solutions given, but nothing worked. So let me ask:

I'm trying to play a sound on an iPhone app when a button is pressed. I imported the Audio framework, hooked up the button with the method, have the WAV sound file in the bundle, and use the following code to play the sound:

```
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"/filename.wav"];
SystemSoundID soundID;
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

But it doesn't play sound when I press a button. (Yes, my sound is on.)

**Any ideas why this might be, and how I can fix it? I'd be happy to provide any more information if it helps.**

Answer (score 17):

First of all, the preferred sound format for iPhone is LE formatted CAF, or mp3 for music.  You can convert a wav to caf with the built in terminal utility:

```
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16 crash.wav crash.caf
```

Then the easiest away to play a sound is to use the AVAudioPlayer... this quick function can help you load a sound resource:

```
- (AVAudioPlayer *) soundNamed:(NSString *)name {
    NSString * path;
    AVAudioPlayer * snd;
    NSError * err;

    path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        snd = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url 
                                                      error:&err] autorelease];
        if (! snd) {
            NSLog(@"Sound named '%@' had error %@", name, [err localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            [snd prepareToPlay];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Sound file '%@' doesn't exist at '%@'", name, path);
    }

    return snd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have solved the problem, but for me, on iOS 7, sometimes the `(__bridge CFURLRef)` casting won't work, in which case, if you print out the result of `(__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]`, it will be `0x0`. This leads to failure of `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID()`. The return value of the function is type of `OSStatus`. If it fails,  the function will return `-50`, which means one or more parameters are invalid. (If it executes successfully, it returns `0`.)

I solved this by using the C style function getting the path of the file:

```
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle ();
    CFURLRef soundFileUrl;

    soundFileUrl = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, CFSTR("fileName"), CFSTR("wav"), NULL);
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileUrl, &soundID);
```